# Angular 2+ Component extends Component fine, but tslint complaining on inherited lifecycle hooks

Tags: angular, tslint

I have an abstract Base Component that cleans subscriptions with oneself:

```html
import { OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export abstract class NeatComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
// Add '.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)' before every '.subscrybe(...)'
// and this subscriptions will be cleaned up on component destroy.

  protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  public ngOnInit(){}
}
```

Now I creating working component:

```html
export class CategorySelectorComponent extends NeatComponent {

    public constructor() { super(); }
    
    public ngOnInit() {
      // some code
    }
}
```

All works fine, but tsLint not likes my ngOnInit method:

> [tslint] Implement lifecycle hook interface OnInit for method ngOnInit
>   in class CategorySelectorComponent
>   (use-life-cycle-interface)

Comment: I also have the issue, it's really annoying that codelyzer can't pick up the inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can override this by making

From :

```
"use-life-cycle-interface": true,
```

to :

```
"use-life-cycle-interface": false,
```

For more detail of test cases , **[Check this out](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/blob/master/test/useLifeCycleInterfaceRule.spec.ts)**

Comment: Thanks! That was easy and helpefull )

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error with a component without heritage, and I correct it adding implement OnDestroy.

Comment: The correct answer, I think.